# How to call a service from XML launch file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an equivalent to rosservice from ROS1 in ROS2?
Much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412657/how-to-call-a-service-from-xml-launch-file?/) by [ROS_Engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/139551/ros_engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For posterity, I found a solution using the executable tag. Let's say you wanted to spawn a second turtle in turtlesim, the below will accomplish this:

```
<executable
    cmd="/spawn turtlesim/srv/Spawn '{x: 1.0, y: 1.0, theta: 0, name: 'custom_turtle'}'"
    cwd="/home"
    launch-prefix="ros2 service call"
    output="screen"
    >
</executable>
```

I don't know what 'cwd' is used for but it should remain as "/home" or else this particular command won't work. You can also combine the launch-prefix and cmd if so desired.

---

Originally posted by [ROS_Engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/139551/ros_engineer/) with karma: 16 on 2023-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0